# 'Unable to execute the desired program' message when attempting to launch Elder Scrolls Online?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-online

When trying to install the Elder Scrolls Online I get the following error:

> Unable to execute the desired program.
>
> Please get another copy of the installer and try again.

Comment: I am attempting to make a more descriptive title which doesn't look like a forum post,

Comment: @Memor-X **Leave the question alone.**  It is *perfectly* stated and you keep changing the entire meaning with every single edit.

Comment: how is my edit changing the meaning, your question body states that the error mentioned you get is when your installing. exactly what my edit is saying

Comment: @John - the way your worded your title isn't how we do things here. We don't pre-pend the title with the game abbreviation, that's what tags are for. We definitely **don't** put 'SOLVED' in the title, that's what Marking your answer as 'accepted' is for (which you can do by clicking the checkmark under the vote count, although you will have to wait a couple of days if it's your own answer).

Comment: Robotnik is correct; please don't revert the question title back to its former state again. This is a clearer title that is more in-line with the expectations of the site.

Comment: I've rolled back the most recent edit and temporarily locked the question. As @Robotnik and others have pointed out, your edits are not how we handle things here, and while I appreciate you are a fan of your edit, it does not match our general quality and question guidelines. For more help, you can always check out the [help center](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/help) to get a better idea of how we do things.

Answer (score 1):

**Quick Answer:** Install the game from another Windows user; if all the users have different My Documents ("User Files") folder locations instead of the default Windows location create a new temporary user to install the game.

---

**Detailed Answer:** As it turns out the installer does NOT like it if you've changed the registry to move the My Documents folder (in Windows 7 Microsoft decided to call it "User Files"). In example since unlike Windows XP where you can simply right-click on the My Documents folder to change it's location you have to go through the registry and manually update the paths and disk id. My installation is to *D:\My Documents* on a RAID 1 SSD setup so if I have to wipe the C:\ for some reason I don't have to worry about moving my files.

I switched to a placeholder account (as Windows user accounts can get corrupted) and was able to initialize the installer. Once it starts verifying (I simply copied an install from my laptop) I switched over and the launcher worked just fine for the user with the My Documents loaded via *D:\My Documents*.

Comment: Just a note on the moving of the folders: It may be easier (and cleaner) to set up directory junctions to the other disk. That way, windows still thinks it's storing things on C:\, but it's actually using folders on D:\